# How to get requested Shipping country in cart item page

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, shipping

How to get requested shipping country id of `checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` on cart item list page `code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/item.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The country ID is saved in the quotes shipping address. Check the CartController `estimatePostAction` method, Here the post for shipping estimation is handled.

Try this

```
$country = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()
             ->getShippingAddress()
             ->getCountryId();
```

Comment: Its correct method to get country ID but its very very slow ....
any alternative way to get it.

Comment: unfortunately this is the only way to get the data from the quote object. You might be able to cut some response time by using `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')` directly but it won't be much

Comment: is this country quote value store in database somewhere?

Comment: yes in the sales address table

Comment: What I did  
`$quoteid= $_SESSION['core']['visitor_data']['quote_id'];
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$table = $resource->getTableName('sales/quote_address');
$query = 'SELECT country_id FROM '. $table.' WHERE quote_id = '. (int)$quoteid.' AND address_type = "shipping" ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1';
$requestcontry = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);`

Is `$requestcontry` will be correct one always?

Comment: Direct queries are always possible but I'm not too sure they're that much faster and it'll stop working if a later Magento version has a different DB layout. It also skips any 3th party extensions that might hook the address retrieval model